# Максимальная длина в массиве с условиями

Tags: c++, алгоритм, поиск, c++17, индексы

Сегодня прошел вступительный экзамен по алгоритмам и была такая задача

---

Экологи собрали почасовые данные об изменении температуры воздуха за последние 10 лет. Их интересуют «периоды жары», то есть такие периоды, которые начинались с температуры выше заданного порога жары, например, 30 градусов, и в каждый следующий час температура не опускалась ниже температуры первого часа:

> [image: Condition]

Напишите псевдокод алгоритма, который получает на вход порог жары и массив температур и находит в этом массиве самый длинный "период жары". Считайте, что размер массива температур не более 10^5, а его элементы - целые числа от -91 до +57.

---

*Не важно, что алгоритм не рассматривает какие-то граничные случаи или что код не скомпилируется. Важна идея и реализация алгоритма самого*

Мое решение:
Идея такова, что просто прямо по массиву проходимся и с помощью условий проверяем их выполнение и если "период жары" заканчивается, то обновляем максимальную длительность. Его сложность O(n). Но где-то внутри себя я чувствую, что он неправильный, пытаюсь найти такие случаи, которые его сломают, но пока что не получается. Прошу помочь разобраться или найти входные данные, при которых алгоритм некорректен (граничные случаи не рассматривать).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // heat - порог жары
    int heat;
    vector<int> temperature;
    // Чтобы не расписывать ввод данных
    cin >> heat >> temperature;

    int max_distance, distance = 0;
    // Индексы начала и конца максимального "периода жары"
    int first_index, last_index = 0;
    // Температура первого часа t_i
    int first_temperature = temperature[0];
    bool flag = false;
    for (int hour = 0; hour < temperature.size(); ++hour) {
        if (temperature[hour] > heat && flag == false) {
            flag = true;
            first_temperature = temperature[hour];
            first_index = hour;
            continue;
        }
        if (temperature[hour] >= first_temperature && flag == true) {
            ++distance;
        } else {
            if (max_distance <= distance) {
                max_distance = distance;
                last_index = hour;
            }
        flag = false;
        distance, first_index, last_index = 0;
    }
    cout << distance << " " << first_index << " " << last_index << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: все правильно. Если существует такой элемент массива который не принадлежал в неубывающий подпоследовательность, значит он принадлежит другой подпоследовательности ненулевого размера. Значит массив можно разбить на такие подпоследовательности и найти в ней макисамльную

Comment: если порога жары меньше значит меньше только первый элемент и он не принадлежит подпоследовательности, значит его можно просто вычеркнуть из вектора.

Comment: Прям точно, что правильно решено? Вы меня прям обрадуете, если правильно :)

Comment: Насчет реализации не уверен, но идея простая и правильная, если именно надо найти ПОДРЯД идущую неубывающую подпоследовательность, выше данного порога

Comment: А почему неубывающая последовательность то? Порог жары например пусть будет 25. И максимальный период жары будет такой: 45 50 46 48 47 51 (в каком-нибудь случае)

Comment: в условии написано, каждый час больше предыдущего в вашем случае это будет 2

Comment: @Neuro, там написано "не опускалась ниже первого часа" т.е последовательность `25 35 27 50 26...` будет вполне корректной.

Comment: Каждый следующий час, не меньше чем первый час написано. Это то есть, если рассматривать мой пример выше, то
50 > 45;
46 > 45;
48 > 45;
...
51 > 45

Comment: Что будет в случае, если единственная высокая температура - на последнем измерении?

Comment: @MBo , тогда такой "период жары" отсутствует, потому что после этой температуры ничего нет, но это граничный случай. Максимальная длительность получается 0

Comment: @Smipe OK, понятно

Comment: @Smipe та формула что у вас написано соответствует тому, что последовательность не убывающая, либо это какая то непонятная задача

Comment: @Neuro, я все равно не понимаю где Вы увидели неубывающую последовательность. t массив температур, чтобы Вас не путать, запишем i = 1 и просто подставим в формулу (i = 1 означает, что максимальный "период жары" начинается с 1 индекса и до n).
{(t_1, ..., t_n): t_1 > порога жары и t_2 > t_1, t_3 > t_1, ... t_n > t_1} а уже последующая температура, которая не вошла в этот период уже будет меньше чем t_1, т.е. t_{n+1} < t_1. Про то, что температуры t_1 <= t_2 <= t_3 <= ... ничего не сказано в задаче

Comment: ну тогда тут только ДП поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришли результаты за экзамен. Задача решена почти правильно, ошибка только в индексах, нужно было правильно реализовать начало и конец максимального "периода жары". Сложность O(n)